# 1st Order DQ Non Homogeneous

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

$$\dfrac{\mathrm dy}{\mathrm dx} + p(x)\cdot y = q(x)$$

The idea behind this is we want the left expression to be in a form of product rule so we would be able to take the integral pretty easily. What if the expressions are not adding but subtracting from each other?

For example, $$\dfrac{\mathrm dy}{\mathrm dx} -(\dfrac 2x)\cdot y= x^3$$

If we use the integrating factor of $e^{\int -\frac2x\,\mathrm dx}$, the factor would be $\dfrac1{x^2}$.  Multiply the factor by the equation and then taking the integral of the left-hand side expression would give $\dfrac1{x^2}\cdot y$.

However, wouldn't what we use only work for product rule for which the form has to be an addition? Because if I take the derivative of $\dfrac 1{x^2}\cdot y$, I would get back an expression with an addition sign instead of subtraction.

thanks!

Answer (score 0):

At first we compute an integrating factor:$$\mu(x)=e^{\int-\frac{2}{x}dx}=\frac{1}{x^2}$$ then we have 
$$\frac{\frac{dy(x)}{dx}}{x^2}-\frac{2y(x)}{x^3}=x$$
and
$$\frac{\frac{dy(x)}{dx}}{x^2}+\frac{d}{dx}\left(\frac{1}{x^2}\right)y(x)=x$$
and this is $$\frac{d}{dx}\left(\frac{y(x)}{x^2}\right)=x$$
Can you finish?
Note that $$-\frac{2}{x^3}=\frac{d}{dx}\left(\frac{1}{x^2}\right)$$

Comment: From the second step to the third step, how did your subtraction become an addition?

Comment: Dear Ace8888, i have added a line for you!

Comment: I see it now, you switched the term (-2/x^3) to it derivative term so that we would have the product form of expression adding another expression. From there we can take the integral, which since it is already in product form the integral of an derivative is just the expression itself.

Comment: ok is your problem solved now?

Comment: Yes, thank you so much!

Comment: Nice that i could help you! Have a nice evening!